# Tabnet Classifier predictions returning 0 and 1 values

Tags: python, classification

I'm trying to build a classification model with tabnet. I want to output probabilities of 0s and 1s (that would be value between 0 and 1). I successfully trained the model but predict function is returning only 0s and 1s and I don't know how to check probabilities. Can you help me out? Here is the code that I'm using:

```
clf = TabNetClassifier(
                optimizer_fn=torch.optim.Adam,
                optimizer_params=dict(lr=0.001),
                scheduler_params={"step_size":50,
                                    "gamma":0.9},
                scheduler_fn=torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR,
                mask_type='sparsemax',
                seed = 7
                )
MAX_EPOCHS = 1000
BATCH_SIZE = int(4096*4)
VIRTUAL_BATCH_SIZE = int(256*4)

hist = clf.fit(
    X_train=X_train.values, y_train=y_train.values,
    eval_set=[
        # (X_train.values, y_train.values), 
        (X_valid.values, y_valid.values)
    ],
    eval_name=[
        'valid'
    ],
    eval_metric=['accuracy','auc'],
    max_epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, 
    patience=15,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    virtual_batch_size=VIRTUAL_BATCH_SIZE,
    num_workers=0,
    weights=1,
    drop_last=False,
)

predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but if similar to sklearn should just be:

```
predictions = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Comment: That actually worked Sam. Thanks a lot! Struggling with the lack of TabNet documentation.

Comment: No problem, had a quick look at the documentation myself and I find it odd it doesn't show the available methods, so just a lucky guess!

I think the key is "TabNet is now scikit-compatible, training a TabNetClassifier or TabNetRegressor is really easy." which means that it should inherit from the scikit classifiers and use the same syntax as those.